# How to modify headers of a fasta file and merge it with the information of another file?

Tags: r, fasta

I have a huge fasta file that has this form:

> HQ323811.1 Abies alba tRNA-Leu (trnL) gene, intron; chloroplast
> GGGCAATCCTGAGCCAAATCCGGTTCATAGAGAAAAGGGTTTCTCTCCTTCTCCTAAGGA
> AAGGGATAGGTGCAGAGACTCAATGG

Then, I have another file that contain the taxonomic information of each organisms inside my fasta file.

I would like to obtain a final fasta file which contain only the scientific name of the species and then the taxonomic information. Is there a way to do this? I have no idea! Could someone please tell me if is there a tutorial or something I can read to try to do it?

Thank you,

Comment: Please give some example data about the taxonomic meta data table (post the first rows)

Comment: Abies alba 
 cellular organisms; Eukaryota; Viridiplantae; Streptophyta; Streptophytina; Embryophyta; Tracheophyta; Euphyllophyta; Spermatophyta; Acrogymnospermae; Pinopsida; Pinidae; Conifers I; Pinales; Pinaceae; Abies

Comment: My final fasta should be like this:

Comment: My final fasta should be like this:   >1;tax=f:Pinaceae, g:Abies, s:Alba and the next line the sequence

Comment: It seems quite impossible to me to get this final output, but maybe there are some tools I can use or maybe combine different commands..

Comment: Things are orders of magnitude easier if your tax table has only canonical names and does not have intermediate clades, e.g. ` Conifers I`

Answer (score 0):

Let there be a file `in.fasta` containing

```
>HQ323811.1 Abies alba tRNA-Leu (trnL) gene, intron; chloroplast
GGGCAATCCTGAGCCAAATCCGGTTCATAGAGAAAAGGGTTTCTCTCCTTCTCCTAAGGA AAGGGATAGGTGCAGAGACTCAATGG
```

And a file `tax.txt` containing one species per line e.g.

```
Abies alba cellular organisms; Eukaryota; Viridiplantae; Streptophyta; Streptophytina; Embryophyta; Tracheophyta; Euphyllophyta; Spermatophyta; Acrogymnospermae; Pinopsida; Pinidae; Conifers I; Pinales; Pinaceae; Abies
```

Then you can run this script in the R programming language

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidysq)

lineages <-
  # Taxon might have multiple intermediate ranks e.g. Conifers I
  # Can not assume just species, genus, family, order, class, phylum, kingdom
  # parsing required
  read_lines("tax.txt") %>%
  tibble(lineage = .) %>%
  mutate(
    # first two words
    species = lineage %>% str_extract("^[A-z0-9]+ [A-z0-9]+"),
    # last word
    genus = lineage %>% str_extract("[A-z0-9]+$")
  )
lineages

read_fasta("in.fasta") %>%
  mutate(species = name %>% str_remove("^[A-z0-9.]+") %>% str_extract("[A-z0-9]+ [A-z0-9]+")) %>%
  left_join(lineages) %>%
  transmute(
    sq,
    name = str_glue("{row_number()}; g:{genus}, s:{species}")
  ) %>%
  {
    .x <- .
    write_fasta(.x$sq, .x$name, "out.fasta")
  }
```

resulting in a file `out.fasta` containing

```
>1; g:Abies, s:Abies alba
GGGCAATCCTGAGCCAAATCCGGTTCATAGAGAAAAGGGTTTCTCTCCTTCTCCTAAGGA AAGGGATAGGTGCAGAGAC
TCAATGG
```

You can also create a file `headers.txt` containing the final headers. The first line is the new name of the first sequence of `in.fasta` and so on:

```
1tax=f:Pinaceae;g:Abies;s:alba
```

The corresponding R script will then be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidysq)

headers <- read_lines("headers.txt")

read_fasta("in.fasta") %>%
  mutate(name = headers) %>%
  {
    .x <- .
    write_fasta(.x$sq, .x$name, "out.fasta")
  }
```

Comment: Omg thanks a lot! But if I modify my taxonomy file by putting f:, g:, s:, before each family, genus and species, could it be easier to obtain my final result? How does the script would change in this case? Because from your output I see there is only genus and species, but I also need the family. Anyway I really appreciate your help, I would never get this from my own

Comment: Well, actually my taxonomy file is too big and every species is more or less classified, so I don't think I can do what I was thinking

Comment: # first two words
    species = lineage %>% str_extract("^[A-z0-9]+ [A-z0-9]+"),
    # last word
    genus = lineage %>% str_extract("[A-z0-9]+$")                                                                      but following this, I could also extract the second last word of the lineage that is always the family, is it right?

Comment: right, yes you can

Comment: #second last word
    family = lineage %>% str_extract("[a-z0-9]+(?=\h+[a-z0-9]+$)                                              Is this correct?

Comment: if there is sth like a sub family or tribe it is not always the second last word

Comment: `lineage %>% str_remove("[A-z0-9]+$") %>% str_extract_all("[A-z0-9]+") %>% simplify() %>% last()` to get the last word before the genus

Comment: Sorry, I modified a bit the script because it was not working properly. I will post it in the next comment. But then the output is this: >1; f:NA, g:NA, s:Abies alba
GGGCAATCCTGAGCCAAATCCGGTTCATAGAGAAAAGGGTTTCTCTCCTTCTCCTAAGGAAAGGGATAGGTGCAGAGACT
CAATGG
>2; f:NA, g:NA, s:Abies alba

Comment: lineages <-
  # Taxon might have multiple intermediate ranks e.g. Conifers I
  # Can not assume just species, genus, family, order, class, phylum, kingdom
  # parsing required
  tibble(lineage = read_lines("lineage.txt")) %>%
  mutate(
    # second word
    species = lineage %>% str_extract("[A-z0-9]+"),
    # last word
    genus = lineage %>% str_extract("[A-z0-9]+$"),
    #second last word
    family =  lineage %>% str_remove("[A-z0-9]+$") %>% str_extract_all("[A-z0-9]+") %>% simplify() %>% last())
lineages

Comment: In addition, by putting the string for the family, I get for every organism that they are from the family Potamogetonaceae... But for example it doesn't even appear in the lineage of Abies alba

Comment: About the Potamogetonaceae, I did a try on a smaller subset and it basically takes the family of the last species of the taxonomy file and it put it for every species

Comment: Are you relying on a specific taxonomy? You can get NCBI taxonomy tables with proper family names here: https://github.com/zyxue/ncbitax2lin. Your current lineage text does not contain precise info about the family.

Comment: I used esearch to download the taxonomy from NCBI, because I have a lot of plants. Maybe the problem is that the file is formatted like this and by copyng and paste here it is not clear: I have Abies Alba in the first line and the rest of the taxonomy in the second line. This for all species. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, my script assumes one species per row.

Comment: Anyway, I modified the file, but still doesn't work properly

Comment: Your lineage data simply does not contain precise info about the family. It can be anywhere. It could sometimes be the second last word, sometimes it might end with ae, other times, it might end with incertae sedis.

Comment: There is `LineageEx` having specific rank info e.g. here: https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=taxonomy&id=45372. In R, there is the apckage xml2 to deal with this

Comment: Yes, I see. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help, you are very kind! I will find out a way to do it! :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I formatted my taxoinomy file as I want. So now in each line I have: >1tax=f:Pinaceae;g:Abies;s:alba.   So how can I now merge my taxonomy file with my fasta file? Thank you!

Comment: @Fran I revised my answer

Comment: Thanks! But what if my fasta has duplicated values? I have different sequences corresponding to the same species, but sometimes they have all the sequence, sometimes just a part, but I need them all. Is it possible?

Comment: Make tables and join them together

Comment: Perfect, thanks!